# CustomViewController throughout Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to display a custom bar that appears on every screen of my application with buttons that work.  I add the CustomViewController to my classes in the init method, and everything works correctly, except when I analyze my application I get a potential memory leak.

When I release [customViewController release], the buttons on the CustomViewController will no longer work.  What is the proper way to go about implementing this solution with no memory leaks.

```
#import "CustomViewController.h"

@implementation CustomViewController

- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender
{
    // Perform an action
}

@end
```

A ViewController which I create the CustomViewController:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil 
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        CustomViewController *customViewController = [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController" bundle:nil];
        UIView *bar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
        [bar addSubview:customViewController.view];
        [self.view addSubview:bar];
        [bar release];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper solution was to create a container view, and place my custom task bar inside of that view.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be going about implementing this the wrong way. What you actually need to do is create CustomViewController and add your toolbar to that view. Every other view controller in your app should then be made a subclass of CustomViewController.

If a custom navigation bar is the only thing you're using this superclass for, I would recommend just styling the bar directly on the UINavigationController your app is using.

Comment: It is not a custom navigation bar, but just a bar that can display elements.  This bar will also vary position depending on the particular view controller.

Comment: Well definitely create your CustomViewController superclass. Add your UIView *bar property to that interface and @synthesize it. From there, your subclasses can position/modify "bar" as you need.

Answer (score -1):

You said your bar has buttons?  Does it release those buttons when it itself is released?  Check it's viewDidLoad function.

Comment: The buttons are connected in interface  builder so no